# mysql 'LIKE' in Django python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am little new to Django,

My Question is How do i do %LIKE% of MYSQL in Django Filter

Want something like this

```
myModel.objects.filter(myField__**like**="xyz")
```

as we can do

```
myModel.objects.filter(myField__startswith="xyz")
```

for strings that starts with 'xyz' but i want to match anywhere in the myField content.

What i know
it can be done by REGEX and .extra() but i want something very straight forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this straight forward answer.if you look at the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
myModel.objects.filter(myField__contains = "xyz")
```

Note: __contains is case sensitive. You can use `__icontains` if you don't care about the case of the text.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `contains` operator `my_model.objects.filter(my_field__contains='xyz')` and `icontains` if you want case insensitivity